# HMM hidden markov model starting point

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I am novice with hidden markov models. What is the minimum starting point to implement a hidden markov model. I mean, what it is necessary to know a priori?. I know in hidden markov models the states are hidden but maybe it is compulsory to know a priory the number of states? the name of the states? other thing? is it necessary a training schema to know some probabilities? any example? In other words, is it possible to implement a hidden markov model without knowing the number of states, their names, ....? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its most basic form a first-order discrete hidden markov model HMM is composed of 5 elements:

1. The number of states *N*
2. The number of the different types of observations *M*
3. The state transition probability distribution *A*.
4. The observations probability distribution *O*
5. The initial state distributions *P*

   So answering your question. Yes, you need to know the number of states a priori because *A* depends on that. You also need to know *M* because *O* depends on that. Depending on the application, you may automatically learn *A*, *O* and *P* from training data. You could also assume that *P* is uniformly distributed or manually set *A* such that the probability of transitioning of one state to itself is high and the probability of transitioning to another different state is lower but this will depend of what you want to achieve and the knowledge you have of the domain.